# Query form data by date to return counts by item and category

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

I'm a teacher and need help with a Google Form that collects the following info:

- Timestamp
- Name
- Class
- Lunch option

All of the data comes into a Google sheet. I'm using successfully using the QUERY function to get the data into separate sheets based on `Class` as I want to keep the data long-term for attendance and `Timestamp` info.

I have another sheet where I would like to show a count for each `Lunch choice` by `Class` and only for the current date.

Here's how the data is laid out in the `'Form Responses'` sheet:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Timestamp** | **Student name** | **Class** | **Lunch choice** |
| **2** | 8/25/2023 8:22:20 | Isaac | Class 1 | Vegan curry |
| **3** | 8/25/2023 8:36:44 | James Clerk | Class 3 | Vegan curry |
| **4** | 8/25/2023 8:51:08 | Albert | Class | Greek salad |
| **5** | 8/25/2023 9:05:32 | Richard | Class 1 | Vegan curry |
| **6** | 8/25/2023 9:19:56 | Edward | Class 1 | Lentil soup |
| **7** | 8/25/2023 9:34:20 | Lisa | Class 3 | Greek salad |
| **8** | 8/25/2023 9:48:44 | Juan Martín | Class 2 | Vegan curry |

I then have a separate sheet called `Lunch` where I would like to get results like this:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Lunch choice** | **Class 1** | **Class 2** | **Class 3** |
| **2** | Greek salad |  | 1 | 1 |
| **3** | Lentil soup | 1 |  |  |
| **4** | Vegan curry | 2 | 1 | 1 |

I don't have much experience with the QUERY function.

- I've tried putting it inside an IF function
- I've tried copying the `Timestamp` into another column so that I can format the date out of the `Timestamp`
- I've tried comparing that date with the TODAY function but it keeps returning `FALSE`.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/171797/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 2):

To get the count of each type of lunch in `D` by classes in `C` where the datetime in `A` is today, use `query()`, like this:

```
=query( 
  'Form Responses'!A1:D, 
  "select D, count(D) 
   where toDate(A) = toDate(now()) 
   group by D 
   pivot C", 
  1 
)
```

See [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the time from the `Timestamp` in order to only consider the date. You can do it using the  INT function.

I don't know what formula you're using, but an example using COUNTIF:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(INT('Form Responses'!A:A)),TODAY())
```

Or you could use it inside COUNTIFS to add other criterion based on your other conditions, or inside FILTER.